# AndEngine + Box2D on Android- how portable is it?

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I'm considering using AndEngine for a physics-based game on Android. A number of the examples (especially the ones I'd be basing my code on) depend on the Box2D extension.

I was surprised to learn that this extension relies on native code for its Box2D implementation, rather than using JBox2D.

How does this limit AndEngine's portability? Will it work on all Android devices?

Answer (score 3):

It won't run on **non-*ARM*** devices, like some currently **very rare** ***x86*** netbooks that have a ported Android version running on them.

Comment: if it ever become a problem. I don't believe it would be too hard to pack a x86 or 64 bit lib alltogether. And add a condition for java to load the appropriate library. It's not like the lib is huge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work on all android devices, as long as you include it in your reference library when building the apk.